# How to return Final Price with Tier pricing taken into account

Tags: magento-1.9, tierprice

Our webshop pricing structure is completely based on Tier pricing. The normal price is set to 999999.99 and occasionally there are special prices that overwrite the Tier price. We need to make an adjustment to the way the price is shown in the category overview. By my knowledge I should use:

```
 <?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice(); >
```

To get the price the logged in customer needs to pay. This should obviously take into account the Tier prices and Special prices if applicable. When I use this I either get the normal price (999999.99) or the special price, but never the actual price (Tier price).

I've also tried calling the Tier prices by using:

```
 <?php echo $_product->getTierPrice(1); ?>
```

This also return 999999,99. I've got this working on the product page. How can I make this work on the category page?